# spans not being appended to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple js issue but can't seem to figure it out. Why are my spans not being appended to the div? jQuery is being loaded just fine, the page isn't throwing any errors, and console.log is outputting the loop correctly.

JS:

```
var matrix = [];
createGrid();
function createGrid () {

    for(var i=0; i < 6; i++) {
        matrix[i] = [];
        for(var j=0; j < 6; j++) {
            log("["+i+"]["+j+"]");
            var $span = $('<span />');
            $("#myGrid").append($span);
        }
    }
}   

function log (w) {
        console.log(w);
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="myGrid"></div>
</body>
```

Output from console: You can see no children are being appended... Why is this?

```
 <div id="myGrid"></div>
```

---

EDIT: I did mention no console errors were thrown, so `log()` wasn't the issue, as I've defined it elsewhere. I was indeed operating on an empty set because the HTML wasn't yet loaded... I needed to have jquery on ready run.

Comment: What about `var $span = "<span>test<span/>";` ...just for testing purposes

Comment: You have to define `createGrid()` before using it. Also remember to put your JS code inside the `$(document).ready()` method.

Comment: It does work http://jsfiddle.net/dqrm07b2/

Comment: @VitoShadow - not true, functions can be declared and called at any time.  This would only be true if he was using `var createGrid = function (){...};`

Comment: check you console. It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: log is not defined". It should be console.log().

Comment: Working for me, Check the error console probably you have an error with log()

Comment: Sorry if I state the obvious, but you do know that the spans will appear over the top of each other due to the CSS? This is working

Comment: @geedubb I know. I wasn't worried about css just  yet

Comment: Ok, sorry then I don't see the issue in the fiddle above - the spans are being appended to the div in the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeing the `log()` calls (meaning you've defined it somewhere else), it's because you're running the JavaScript before the HTML is loaded, as  you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/dqrm07b2/1/

Basically, the operations on `$('#myGrid').append($span)` is not doing anything because `$('#myGrid')` is returning an empty set.

I know some people love this silent error feature in jQuery, but I hate it. Trying to operate on an empty set should throw an error, it's hidden so many bugs for me.

Comment: Excellent description of the issue and I also hate the silent error issues. I wish it would tell me it was an empty set then I would know that I was operating before HTML was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You might be trying to query the DOM before its ready.
Wrap all your code in a jQuery function to test if this is the case:

```
$(function(){

 //your code here

});
```

Edit:
In response to "log is not a function", the question states that he is able to see output in console. From this I had assumed that console.log was aliased: function wrapper, library helper.. so on. Post says that it works and I'm running with it.

In the future the following techniques might be of help to you in debugging DOM problems:

1) Put an alert($("selector_you_want_to_test")[0])
    This will pause the browser and you can inspect the state of the DOM tree construction in the developer tools window

2) Put in a debugger statement

3) For very large projects: Take a timeline profile (in google chome), the profile will show you when the DOM was finished and when your function ran. This view makes it very easy to reason about time sensitive problems like this.

Good Luck

Comment: Removed my answer after those downvotes but to me, `log`  is not a JS function. The main issue is what you pointed out, I guess.

Comment: this answer does not work...log isnt a function like @sodawillow said. whether you wrap it in a $(function() {}); or not.

Comment: @sodawillow I agree not obvious from the question

Comment: @Growler See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27805282/227299) for an explanation as to why you don't get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Tryout a code like the following and make sure your code after the div or use `document.ready()`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
        #myGrid {
            position: relative;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: silver;
        }

        #myGrid > span {
           /* position: ;*/
            width : 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: white;
        }


    </style>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="myGrid"></div>
  <script>
     var matrix = [];
            createGrid();
            function createGrid () {

                for(var i=0; i < 6; i++) {
                    matrix[i] = [];
                    for(var j=0; j < 6; j++) {
                       // console.log("["+i+"]["+j+"]");
                        var span = '<span>'+i+'</span>';
                        $("#myGrid").append(span);
                    }
                }
            }   
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/nezinixaza/1/

Comment: I have started writing and investigating for this answer during some of those answers have been wrote, so I did not like to waste the time that I have spent to answer it. @JuanMendes

Answer (score 0):

you had a "log" function or whatever i think you wanted to be "console.log"

your code otherwise does what its supposed to do, but i think this is what you actually want it to do: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/27/

```
var matrix = [];
createGrid();
function createGrid () {

    for(var i=0; i < 6; i++) {
        matrix[i] = [];
        for(var j=0; j < 6; j++) {
            console.log("["+i+"]["+j+"]");
            var $span = "<span>["+i+"]["+j+"]</span><br/>";
            $("#myGrid").append($span);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP said there were no errors on the console, therefore `log` must be defined somewhere else.